# Remove <object> from dom on ipad

Tags: javascript, html, ipad

I'm working on a projet where a page is loaded through an object that is dynamically generated with jquery. This is an iPad project.

When the user is done with page there is a call to remove the object from the dom. Using something like $('#objectName').remove(); crashes safari on ipad. This does not happen on the desktop browsers. I tried to use an iframe but the result is the same.

How can I remove the object without the iPad crashing?

I tried wrapping the object in a div and removing or hiding that div but with weird results. It crashes still when I remove the div and hiding the div still leaves the object visible.

Thanks for all of the help!

Comment: Have you tried jQuery's empty() or detatch() to see if that makes any difference?

Comment: Yes, these methods produce the same result. It seems that removing the object from the dom makes the ipad crash.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a pretty old thread, but for the people who run into this I have a fix for the problem:

For me, the issue only appeared when I was trying to remove an object from the DOM with an iframe in it.

To fix it, I first tried setting the iframe's src to nothing before(!) removing the element from the DOM like this:

```
$('div.lightbox iframe').attr('src','');
```

This didn't fix the issue completely, it worked but when it was the case that the iframe content was still loading when I removed the element from the DOM (I was loading the content in a lightbox element, and closing the lightbox (thus removing the element from the DOM) it still crashed the browser.

I fixed the issue completely by setting the HTML of the element to be removed to nothing, again before(!) removing the element from the DOM like this:

```
$('div.lightbox').html('');
```

So here, the final solution:

```
$("div.lightbox").fadeOut(500, function(){

    $('div.lightbox iframe').attr('src',''); 
    $('div.lightbox').html(''); 

}).remove();
```